# How to I replace all code in trunk with my old code?

Tags: svn, merge

A partner and I are using svn for a partner project for a class, and we initially went the wrong direction with the code in our trunk. We got to revision 129 before realizing we would be better off starting over from revision 113, and going a different direction.

On my own computer I checked out revision 113, made the changes, and want to commit the code I have. However, when I try to commit I get this:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File or directory 'Robot.cpp' is out of date; try updating
svn: resource out of date; try updating
```

The problem is, I don't want to update. I don't want all the changes we made from revision 113 to 129, and basically want to replace all the code in the repository with what I have locally. How would I do this?

Comment: If you can install a GUI like TortoiseSVN, you may find the ability to drag-and-drop gets rid of the arcaneness of figuring out the right command line.

Comment: Quirky alternative: Delete the newer revisions files and edit the "current" file. I think you can find a tutorial on this on the web. It is unsupported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being at the root of your working copy, you can issue the following command:

```
svn merge -rHEAD:113 .
```

This will '*undo*' all your changes from revision 113 so that your revision 130 will look like revision 113.

Don't forget to commit afterwards though.

Answer (score 3):

- Tag current trunk so you have a backup
- Checkout the current copy into a new folder
- Rollback all changesto version 113: `svn merge -c 113` and then `svn commit -m
  "rolledback to 113"`.
- In your current working directory: `svn update`
- Then `svn commit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can tag the version 129, and download the version of 129 to you local. Use you new local version create a new branch. In this way, you can keep everything you have. On one branch, you can fix problem on version 129, on other branch, you can create new functions. You can also merge changes from one branch to another.